# convert number into binary and Count consecutive 1's in binary number in java

Tags: java, binary

I have written below code for displaying count for consecutive 1's in binary number e.g if input is 13 1101 then count should be 2 .

But testcase has failed for 1911

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author jyotiv
 *
 */
public class BinaryConversion {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int n=0,count=1;
    String binaryNo="";
    int sum=0;
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=scanner.nextInt();
    binaryNo=Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    System.out.println(binaryNo);
char binaryArray[]=binaryNo.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<binaryArray.length-1;i++)
    {       
        //System.out.print(binaryArray[i]);
        if(binaryArray[i]==binaryArray[i+1])
        {
        count++;    
        }


    }
    System.out.println(count);
}

}
```

Comment: why don't you use a debugger with step by step mode to inspect your application behavior?

Comment: *testcase has failed* Define "failed." What happened - wrong output? Exception?

Comment: Did it ever occur to you that `1911` is not a binary number?

Comment: @CardinalSystem Yeah, I was going to ask about that, too.

Comment: By "conjugative", do you mean "[consecutive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/consecutive?s=t)", as in "following one another in uninterrupted succession or order"? If so, then you need to reset the counter when seeing a 0, and only increment the counter when seeing a 1, and then remember the *largest* count you see. Decimal `1911` is binary `11101110111`, and highest number of consecutive 1's is **3**. For a better test, try decimal `1475`, binary `10111000011`, which has 3 consecutive 1's, and the 4 consecutive 0's don't count.

Comment: yes.. Consecutive .. :)

Comment: @Andreas It worked thanks..

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments - it's not readable in that format.

Comment: @EJoshuaS  ok Sir. I Will follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


/**
 * @author jyotiv
 *
 */
public class BinaryConversion{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n=0,countOne=0,maxCount = 0;
        String binaryNo="";
        int sum=0;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=scanner.nextInt();
        binaryNo=Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        System.out.println(binaryNo);
        char binaryArray[]=binaryNo.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<binaryArray.length;i++)
        {       
            //System.out.print(binaryArray[i]);

            if(binaryArray[i]=='1')
            {
                countOne++; 
            //}
            }
            if(countOne>maxCount)
            {
                maxCount=countOne;
            }
            if(binaryArray[i]=='0')
            {
                countOne=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxCount);
    }

}
```

It works with the above modification

Comment: Input `1475`, output `4`, but correct answer is `3`.

Comment: With updated code: Input `1475`, output `1`, but correct answer is `3`.

Comment: @Andreas the code should finally work. Please check

Comment: Yes, you now have similar code to what OP pasted as [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002701/convert-number-into-binary-and-count-consecutive-1s-in-binary-number-in-java/48003014?noredirect=1#comment82974333_48002701) 9 minutes earlier.